# How to Compare Two String With Optional Characters?

Tags: python, regex, django, string-comparison, regex-greedy

consider we have a function (in Django || python) which compares two strings, one is the correct answer and another is student answered string.

```
correct = '(an) apple (device)'
student_answerd = 'apple device'
```

I want to check student_answered with the correct string but parentheses are optional it means all the below student_answered is correct:

```
    case 1: an apple device
    case 2: an apple
    case 3: apple device
    case 4: apple
```

notice: we don't have the same correct format for all questions it means the location of parentheses is different for example maybe we just have one parentheses or more.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You can use regexes for this. Then the regex could look like `'(an)? ?apple?(device)?'`, and it will be matched with the student's answer.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem could you please write the pseudocode?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/dmUqUc/1/codegen?language=python

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, here we could ignore <kbd>(</kbd> and <kbd>)</kbd> and see the desired output:

```
(.*?)(?:[()]|)
```

#### RegEx

If this wasn't your desired expression, you can modify/change your expressions in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/BKRKGL/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

You can also visualize your expressions in [jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

#### JavaScript Demo

```js
const regex = /(.*?)(?:[()]|)/gm;
const str = `(an) apple (device)
apple device`;
const subst = `$1`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

#### Python Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"(.*?)(?:[()]|)"

test_str = ("(an) apple (device)\n"
    "apple device")

subst = "\\1"

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

---

#### RegEx

If you wish to literally check for correct answers, you might want to do it word by word. Maybe, this expression would work:

```
^((an|one)?(\s?)([aple]+)?(\s?)([devic]+)?)$
```

[image]

#### Python Code

You can simply add an `if` for match and not match:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import re

string = "an apple device"
expression = r'^((an|one)?(\s?)([aple]+)?(\s?)([devic]+)?)$'
match = re.search(expression, string)
if match:
    print("YAAAY! \"" + match.group(1) + "\" is a match  ")
else: 
    print(' Sorry! No matches!')
```

#### Output

```
YAAAY! "an apple device" is a match
```

#### JavaScript Demo for Full Match and Groups

```js
const regex = /^((an|one)?(\s?)([aple]+)?(\s?)([devic]+)?)$/gm;
const str = `an apple device
an apple
apple device
apple
one apple
one appl device
two apple deive
on apple device
a apple device`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Then, you can add any other chars that you wish to the list, such as parentheses:

```
^(((one|an)+)?(\s?)([aple()]+)?(\s?)([()devic]+)?)$
```

[image]

This would also pass some misspelled words, which I 'm guessing that would be desired. If not, you can simply remove `[]` and use capturing groups with logical ORs:

```
(apple|orange|banana)?
```

Comment: That's good but I need some codes to return me true or false, 
for example, if a student writes "Two Apple Devices" I want to get false compare result.

notice: all characters are already converted to .lower()

Comment: Miss understanding buddy
forget the last sample, consider we have a string like (a) hardhat(s)
parentheses are optional it means:
a hardhats is OK
hardhats is OK
a hardhat is OK
and so on ... the parentheses are optional and remain is forced.

Answer (score 0):

```
"apple" in student_answer #matches 'papple'
```

or

```
"apple" in student_answer.split() # doesn't match 'papple'
```

Additionally, you can replace common additives.

```
a = [',', 'an', ' ', 'device']
for i in a:
    student_answer = student_answer.replace(a, '')
student_answer == 'apple'
```